# Parsing concurrency '${addressThread}' in group 'ThreadGroup' failed, choose 1

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I am trying to define a percentage of threads for each ThreadGroup in my load testing .jmx file, and pass the total number of threads from taurus config .yaml file.

However, taurus fails to parse the expression, even though when I try to debug it using jmeter I can see that the expressions works. ( I am setting the total number of users in `user.property` file in jmeter).

This is my yaml config file.

```
---
scenarios:
  student_service:
    script: ~/jmeter/TestPlan.jmx
    variables:
      addressThread: 100
    think-time: 500ms

execution:
  - scenario: student_service
    hold-for: 5m
```

[image: tried here just regular variable]

versions I am using:

> 1. Taurus CLI Tool
> 2. MacOs10.13.6
> 3. Jmeter 5.0

Comment: I added a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing properties and variables.

It should be:

```
---
scenarios:
  student_service:
    script: ~/jmeter/TestPlan.jmx
    properties:
      addressThread: 100
    think-time: 500ms

execution:
  - scenario: student_service
    hold-for: 5m
```

And in JMeter, you should be using [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function:

> ${__P(addressThread)}

Still, there is a bug in current version of Taurus 1.13.2, so you need to wait for next version:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codename-taurus/QggRz9QDnO0/_FEGllDoGAAJ

Comment: I tried using your yaml config, and my ThreadGroup is looking for ${__P(addressThread)}. but I still get 
" WARNING: Parsing concurrency '${__P(addressThread)}' in group 'ThreadGroup' failed, choose 1"

Comment: I was able to read the property after I upgraded to Taurus 1.13.3.